# migrations and TinyTds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

I am trying use migrations in a rails project with a sql server database, but when I do a `rack db:migrate` command I receive this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'TEST'.: CREATE TABLE [schema_migrations] ([version] nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: show me your database.yml

Comment: probably you don't have user privileges for CREATE on your db